# Overflow with Socket buffer in a C# / Perl connection

Tags: c#, perl, sockets, buffer

I have a TCP Socket beetwen two programs, a C# server and a Perl client. The client is supposed to receive an XML stream from the server. The XML file (generated by the C# program) is around 437KB but the client only receives 408KB no matter how big is the buffer. On the client side I use *IO::Socket::INET* while the server side uses a combination of *TcpListener* and *TcpClient*. How can I properly define the buffer on the client side? Right now I am using that code:

```
# PERL CLIENT
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    PeerHost => '192.168.*.*',
    PeerPort => '*****',
    Proto => 'tcp'
) or die "Error while creating Socket";
#
# OTHER STUFFS...
#
my $buffer = 500000000; # IT DOESNT SEEM TO USE THAT VALUE AT ALL
$socket->recv($xmlbody, $buffer);


// C# SERVER
// OTHER STUFFS...
byte[] result = encoding.GetBytes(xml);
clientStream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
clientStream.Flush();
clientStream.Close();
tcpClient.Close();
```

Comment: Sounds like the sender is buffered, and that you need to flush the buffer. You could verify that this a problem on the sender's side using `tcpdump` or the like.

Comment: Are you closing the stream after sending the XML? Or are you prefixing the XML with its length? What I'm getting at is how do you know how many bytes the reader should read?

Comment: Yes the server is flushing and closing the stream after he has sent the XML. The fact is that I don't know how many bytes the reader should read, it's quite random and I never had this problem until the XML file became so big in size. Are you suggesting to send to the receiver the lenght of the file first?

Comment: Closing the sender is sufficient signal to indicate when to stop reading. If you didn't do that, then I would recommend sending the length. Since you do, there's no need to send the length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never use `recv`, so I don't know its quirks. I use `sysread`.

```
sub read_until_eof {
   my ($fh) = @_;
   my $buf = '';
   for (;;) {
      my $rv = sysread($fh, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf))
      die $! if !defined($rv);
      return $buf if !$rv;
   }
}
```

If this doesn't do it, I suggest you use `tcpdump` to ascertain whether the problem is in the sender, the receiver, or somewhere in between.

---

`sysread`'s and `read`'s "quirks":

`sysread` always returns as soon as bytes bytes available, regardless of how many bytes were requested. That means it returns immediately if bytes are already available when it is called. It will block until a packet comes in otherwise. That means one needs to loop if one wants a specific number of characters.

In contrast, `read` waits until the requested number of bytes are available. It only returns then, on EOF or on error.

`read` and `sysread` actually work at the character level, which means you actually specify a number of characters desired, not a number of bytes. Those characters could be bytes, Unicode code points or whatever depending on what IO layer you added to the handle.

Comment: I never used sysread, always recv but hey, that worked just fine! Thank you all guys for the help!

Comment: @raz3r, I should have mentioned `sysread`'s "quirks". Adding them now.